# How to use step by step trx framework for iso 8583?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, iso8583, trx

Hello I am first in iso 8583 project, i use .net for create the project and i use trx framework? can you help me to use trx framework ? :D

Comment: Is this still a valid question? I have been using Trx framework for the past 8 months and got into many situations. Earned some experience on this subject.

Comment: Yes now I am use Trx framework , but very little documention , the TCP  for sending message is suck, not comfortable and failed with our partner ISO server, don't know why ...
are using Trx too ?? for your project ??

Comment: Yes, I have implemented a protocol based on IFSF (ISO 8583 based protocol) using Trx. I also had a lot of problems. You probably need to mess up with the Formatters and also create some custom formatting too. It all depends to the specific implementation you need.

ISO 8583 is just a specification for the formmatting of the message.  Each implementation has it's own requirements and customisations. Take a look at the example projects coming with the Trx download.
I suggest you ask a more specific question, because this one is too general.

Comment: Yes, i and my friend salcad modified this framework for custom message  and work fine.

Comment: @Thanasis I can't find any documentation. I simple send a financial transaction. from a test tool (BP-Sim Framework) I can see the response coming but I can't find any nay to get that response

Comment: @KamranShahid yeah the documentation not good , and maybe you need debug because the response message each server probably different , probably have unique character iso. have you debug inside the response ? what framework that you use ?

Comment: Not good? I didn't find any documentation for Trx framework.http://sourceforge.net/projects/trx-framework/ . Can you please share the link. Yep I have done some debugging inside the framework for certain needs

Comment: question for @masadizainul: Do you some code you can share with me to communicate using the IFSF procotol?

Comment: @PieroAlberto , emm in my implementation doesn't have communication using IFSF ..

Comment: masadi please let me know if you have used connected socket or on demand connection